# Reuse session variables while opening a browser with selenium webdriver

Tags: vb.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, automation

When opening a new browser doing

```
Dim driver As IWebDriver
```

the session variables are lost, I have thought about saving these variables in xml files to reload them in the webdriver browser, but it really doesn't seem like the best option. Is there a way to pass these session variables to the new browser in Visual Basic and Firefox Driver?

Answer (score 0):

When you configure an instance of a *WebDriver* using

```
Dim driver As IWebDriver
```

the configuration gets **baked** into the *webdriver* session and will persist till the lifetime of the *WebDriver* being **uneditable**.

Even if you are able to extract the *Session* attributes e.g. **Session ID**, **Cookies**, **UserAgent** and other session attributes from the already initiated *WebDriver* still you won't be able to pass them while initiating a new *WebDriver* session.

Comment: Therefore it is impossible to do what I intend? I tried this: https://tarunlalwani.com/post/reusing-existing-browser-session-selenium-csharp/ but when I try to do OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.Response it says 'not defined'

Comment: Rather then _tarun_ I tend to follow the WebDriver Specification.

Comment: Ok, so, what alternatives do you think I have in this case? I find it hard to believe that the best solution is to use the XML...